# Fastest way to check if a given array value matches another array value?

Tags: php, arrays

I know this is a 0(n) relationship, where we need to check for every single row of array for membership, but what is the fastest way to do the check?

```
$x = [["id" =>61, "name" => "jill"],["id" =>1, "name" => "john"],];
$y = [["id" =>89, "state" => "drunk"],["id" =>61, "state" => "sleep"]];

$z = array_values_collide($x, $y, "id");
```

where z should return:

```
$z = [["id" =>61, "name" => "jill", state => "sleep"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all elements in `$x` that are also in `$y`. The result is called the *intersection of both arrays*. See function [array_intersect_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php). I am sure PHP developers took care of implementing it to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_intersect_assoc to get the values which are present both arrays. And/or check the other intersect commands.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php